# How can we override the existing deployer customization in Tridion 2009?

Tags: tridion, tridion-content-delivery, tridion2009, tridion-deploy-extension

While in process of customizing Deployer, I noticed that we have already customized **PageDeploy** and **PageUndeploy** modules, please see the below config sections taken from  cd_deployer_conf.xml.

PageDeploy:

```xml
<Module Type="PageDeploy"
        Class="com.tridion.extensions.deployer.ConditionalPageDeploy">
   <Transformer Class="com.tridion.deployer.TCDLTransformer" />
</Module>
```

PageUndeploy:

```xml
<Module Type="PageUndeploy"
        Class="com.tridion.extensions.deployer.ConditionalPageUndeploy"/>
```

I just have their .jar file no code as this was done by SDL Tridion when they implemented Tridion in our company, now I want to implement one new process when page is published or unpublished.

What changes do I need to do so that without touching existing customization, I can implment the new customization. Is it permitiable or supported in Tridion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to ask around in your department. Typically Tridion Professional Services will leave the code for any customization they make at the customer's site, specifically so that you can make changes to it afterwards.

Alternatively, you can create an additional Deploy/Undeploy module for your functionality. There can be multiple modules per type, so you can just add your own module to the list.

Comment: Thanks Frank, ok you mean I can add my custom module like this <Module Type="CustomPageUndeploy" Class="com.tridion.custom.pageundeployer"/> can you also please suggest on this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773243/how-to-customize-deployer-for-pagedeploy-and-undeploy-module-in-tridion-2009)

Comment: You can add your own indeed and/or get/find the code of the customization that was created for you. There is no need to point me to other questions. If is is related to Tridion, I've already seen it.